# How can I become root user and taking the logs using one command

Tags: android, logcat

In android terminal I run an application. In order to see the logs I execute two commands.

```
$su
$logcat -b main
```

How can I short these 2 commands in 1?

Answer (score 1):

`su` supports command as an argument:

```
$su logcat -b main
```

Comment: when I execute $su logcat -b main 
it returns : Unknown id: logcat

Comment: check that the logcat executable is in your path, or execute from the folder it lives in,  `su /path/to/folder/logcat -b main`

Comment: How can I find out, in which folder the logcat is stored?